# Playframework 2.5 and Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.5

I am using IDEA for my Playframework development. However, I don't seem to be able to run/debug my application anymore I was able to do two months ago. I haven't done any active development on this project, and there have been updates to IDEA.

When I now debug my application it doesn't not load the 'dev' configuration file.
This is specified as `-Dconfig.resource=application.dev.conf` under JVM options on the Run/Debug configurations.

This used to work fine, but it now loads the application.conf which contains the default db parameters to connect to a MySQL server and not the mem server. I don't think I have changed anything. A ny pointers what can be wrong?

I am still on sbt-plugin 2.5.16.

[Edit]

```
Loading config from properties {jline.esc.timeout=0, config.resource=application.dev.conf, java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, sun.boot.library.path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib, java.vm.version=25.25-b02, user.country.format=IE, gopherProxySet=false, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, path.separator=:, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, user.country=GB, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, sun.os.patch.level=unknown, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, user.dir=/Users/xxx/Documents/Java/Y2kBooking, java.runtime.version=1.8.0_25-b17, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment, java.endorsed.dirs=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/endorsed, os.arch=x86_64, java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/6g/mllv8zcn73v3p9mgt8f78jd80000gn/T/, line.separator=
, java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, os.name=Mac OS X, sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8, java.library.path=/Users/xxx/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:., jboss.modules.system.pkgs=com.intellij.rt, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, java.class.version=52.0, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, os.version=10.13.2, http.nonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16, user.home=/Users/xxx, user.timezone=Europe/Dublin, java.awt.printerjob=sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob, java.specification.version=1.8, file.encoding=UTF-8, user.name=xxx, java.class.path=/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.3/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2017.3/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar, jline.shutdownhook=false, java.vm.specification.version=1.8, sun.arch.data.model=64, java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre, sun.java.command=xsbt.boot.Boot run, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, user.language=en, awt.toolkit=sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit, config.trace=loads, java.vm.info=mixed mode, java.version=1.8.0_25, java.ext.dirs=/Users/xxx/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java, sun.boot.class.path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/classes:/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2017.3/captureAgent/debugger-agent-storage.jar, java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, file.separator=/, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, sun.cpu.endian=little, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeBig, socksNonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16, ftp.nonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16, sun.cpu.isalist=}
Loading config from class loader sbt.PluginManagement$PluginClassLoader@4cc89246 but there were no resources called application.dev.conf
exception loading application.dev.conf: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.dev.conf
Loading config from a String akka {
  log-dead-letters = 0
  log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = off
}
Loading config from resource 'reference.conf' URL jar:file:/Users/xxx/.ivy2/cache/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-js-engine/jars/sbt-js-engine-1.1.3.jar!/reference.conf from class loader sbt.PluginManagement$PluginClassLoader@4cc89246
Loading config from a URL: jar:file:/Users/xxx/.ivy2/cache/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-js-engine/jars/sbt-js-engine-1.1.3.jar!/reference.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the configuration loading with `-Dconfig.trace=loads` as described [here](https://github.com/lightbend/config#debugging-your-configuration).

The `-Dconfig.resource` option loads a file from the *classpath* so make sure that file is in your IntelliJ classpath. I assume you put the file in the usual `conf` directory? You may need to check the IntelliJ Project Structure settings to make sure it includes that directory as a *Resource Folder*.

Finally, you may wish to check that the application works correctly when run using `sbt run` or `sbt start`.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the resource file cannot be found. But it is in the conflict directory, and it used to work fine a few months ago. I added the log above. It does load the application.conf instead, which is in the same directory. I will have a look at the class paths.